# Storing print output

Tags: r, loops, if-statement

I am simulating football results using R, I have set up a loop where each team plays against each other.

```
mod3=glm(formula = Score ~ Attack +Home+Division , family = poisson,    data = football)
for (i in 1:20){
for (j in 1:20){
 if (i!=j){

  teamHome=levels(football$Attack)[i] 
  teamAway=levels(football$Attack)[j]
 teamHome
 teamAway
 if(i<21){
 iteam="P"
} else if(i<45){
 iteam="C"
} else if(i<69){
iteam="1"
 } else{
 iteam="2"
 }
 if(j<21){
  jteam="P"
 } else if(j<45){
 jteam="C"
  } else if(j<69){
  jteam="1"
   } else{
  jteam="2"
   }

 if(iteam==jteam) {iteam <- "S"; jteam <-"S"}

 DivisionS=paste(iteam,jteam,"      ",sep="")
DivisionJ=paste(jteam,iteam,"      ",sep="")
 homeScore=rpois(1,predict.glm(mod3, data.frame(Attack=teamHome,Home="Y   ",Division=DivisionS),type="response"))
     awayScore=rpois(1,predict.glm(mod3, data.frame(Attack=teamAway, Home="N   ",Division=DivisionJ),type="response"))
     Result= if(homeScore>awayScore){
        Result="H"
  } else if(homeScore<awayScore){
     Result="A"
 }else if(homeScore==awayScore){
   Result="D"
}
         results<-print(paste(teamHome,homeScore,"      ",teamAway,awayScore,DivisionS,DivisionJ,Result),quote=F)
```

When I run my loop I get results like:

```
  [1] QPR                    0        Arsenal                1 SS       SS       A
  [1] QPR                    1        Tottenham              1 SS       SS       D
  [1] QPR                    2        Everton                1 SS       SS       H
  [1] QPR                    1        Liverpool              2 SS       SS       A
  [1] QPR                    2        WBA                    1 SS       SS       H
  [1] QPR                    0        Swansea                2 SS       SS       A
```

Where I need the results to be stored at different levels so I can tally the amount of `H` and `A` and `D` with the right team, and the number of goals a team scored or conceded.

How can I store my print output ?

Comment: `split(data, data$Result)`

Comment: @RichardScriven when I run that it says `Error in split.default(x = seq_len(nrow(x)), f = f, drop = drop, ...) : 
  group length is 0 but data length > 0`. Should I be saving my results differently ?

Comment: You are not storing results here, just printing then and then the result is copied over. Try saving each iteration in a list eg list(teamHome,homeScore,,teamAway,awayScore,Result). Hard to give more info without seeing any data or your code.

Comment: @user20650 Hi, I'll edit initial question with my code used, to see if you have any thoughts on how I could solve this

Comment: @StephenDakin; thanks for the update.  From a quick look, why do you have lines with  conditions i(or j)< 45 & i<69 when they are both defined to go from 1 to 20?

Comment: @user20650 sorry they should be i(1:92) and j(1:92), I ws just checking the results between the first 20. any thoughts on my initial problem